How can i map DTO to entity in typescript?
In my project, I use Vue + TypeScript and Axios to get objects from the backend. So, I have an object type like this:
class Annoucement {
    id!: string;
    description?: string;
    deal?: Deal;
    realty?: Realty;
    user?: User; 
}

and a response like this:
{
  "id": "guid",
  "description": "string",
  "deal": {
     //...
  },
  "realty": {
     //...
  },
  "user": {
     //...
  }
}

The main problem is that deal and reality can have different properties, thats why I cant just use something like this
let annoucement = new Annoucement();
annoucement.realty.floor = dto.realty.floor;
//...

EDIT:
These are my classes
    class Deal {
        private _id!: string;
    
        private _dealInfo!: Sell | Rent; 
    
        public get id(): string {
            return this._id;
        }
    
        public set id(value: string) {
            this._id = value;
        }
    
        public get dealInfo(): Sell | Rent {
            return this._dealInfo;
        }
    
        public set dealInfo(value: Sell | Rent) {
            this._dealInfo = value;
        }
    
        public constructor(id: string) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    class Sell extends Deal {
    
        public readonly dealType: string = "Sell";
    
        private _conditions!: SellConditions;
    
        public get conditions(): SellConditions {
            return this._conditions;
        }
    
        public set conditions(value: SellConditions) {
            this._conditions = value;
        }
    
        public constructor(id: string, conditions: SellConditions) {
            super(id);
            this.conditions = conditions;
        }
    } 


    class SellConditions {
        private _id!: string;
    
        public get id(): string {
            return this._id;
        }
    
        public set id(value: string) {
            this._id = value;
        }
    
        private _price!: number;
    
        public get price(): number {
            return this._price;
        }
    
        public set price(value: number) {
            this._price = value;
        }
    
        private _type?: string | undefined;
    
        public get type(): string | undefined {
            return this._type;
        }
    
        public set type(value: string | undefined) {
            this._type = value;
        }
    
        private _yearInOwn!: number;
    
        public get yearInOwn(): number {
            return this._yearInOwn;
        }
    
        public set yearInOwn(value: number) {
            this._yearInOwn = value;
        }
    
        private _ownersCount!: number;
    
        public get ownersCount(): number {
            return this._ownersCount;
        }
    
        public set ownersCount(value: number) {
            this._ownersCount = value;
        }
    
        private _prescribersCount!: number;
    
        public get prescribersCount(): number {
            return this._prescribersCount;
        }
    
        public set prescribersCount(value: number) {
            this._prescribersCount = value;
        }
    
        private _haveChildOwners!: boolean;
    
        public get haveChildOwners(): boolean {
            return this._haveChildOwners;
        }
    
        public set haveChildOwners(value: boolean) {
            this._haveChildOwners = value;
        }
    
        private _haveChildPrescribers!: boolean;
    
        public get haveChildPrescribers(): boolean {
            return this._haveChildPrescribers;
        }
    
        public set haveChildPrescribers(value: boolean) {
            this._haveChildPrescribers = value;
        }
    }

    class Rent extends Deal {
        public readonly dealType: string = "Rell";
    
        private _conditions!: RentConditions;
    
        public get conditions(): RentConditions {
            return this._conditions;
        }
    
        public set conditions(value: RentConditions) {
            this._conditions = value;
        }
    
        public constructor(id: string, rentConditions: RentConditions) {
            super(id);
            this.conditions = rentConditions;
        }
    }
    
    class RentConditions {
        private _id!: string;
    
        public get id(): string {
            return this._id;
        }
    
        public set id(value: string) {
            this._id = value;
        }
    
        private _price!: number;
    
        public get price(): number {
            return this._price;
        }
    
        public set price(value: number) {
            this._price = value;
        }
    
        private _period?: string | undefined;
    
        public get period(): string | undefined {
            return this._period;
        }
    
        public set period(value: string | undefined) {
            this._period = value;
        }
    
        private _deposit!: number;
    
        public get deposit(): number {
            return this._deposit;
        }
    
        public set deposit(value: number) {
            this._deposit = value;
        }
    
        private _communalPays!: number;
    
        public get communalPays(): number {
            return this._communalPays;
        }
    
        public set communalPays(value: number) {
            this._communalPays = value;
        }
    
        private _prepay!: number;
    
        public get prepay(): number {
            return this._prepay;
        }
    
        public set prepay(value: number) {
            this._prepay = value;
        }
    
        private _facilities?: string | undefined;
    
        public get facilities(): string | undefined {
            return this._facilities;
        }
    
        public set facilities(value: string | undefined) {
            this._facilities = value;
        }
    
        private _withKids!: boolean;
    
        public get withKids(): boolean {
            return this._withKids;
        }
    
        public set withKids(value: boolean) {
            this._withKids = value;
        }
    
        private _withAnimals!: boolean;
    
        public get withAnimals(): boolean {
            return this._withAnimals;
        }
    
        public set withAnimals(value: boolean) {
            this._withAnimals = value;
        }
    
        private _canSmoke!: boolean;
    
        public get canSmoke(): boolean {
            return this._canSmoke;
        }
    
        public set canSmoke(value: boolean) {
            this._canSmoke = value;
        }
    }

    class Reality {
        private _id!: string;
    
        public get id(): string {
            return this._id;
        }
    
        public set id(value: string) {
            this._id = value;
        }
    
        private _area!: number;
    
        public get area(): number {
            return this._area;
        }
    
        public set area(value: number) {
            this._area = value;
        }
    
        private _type?: string | undefined;
    
        public get type(): string | undefined {
            return this._type;
        }
    
        public set type(value: string | undefined) {
            this._type = value;
        }
    
        public constructor(id: string, area: number, type?: string | undefined) {
            this.id = id;
            this.area = area;
            this.type = type;
        }
    }

class Office extends CommercialBuilding {

    private _name?: string | undefined;

    public get name(): string | undefined {
        return this._name;
    }
    public set name(value: string | undefined) {
        this._name = value;
    }

    private _roomsCount!: number;

    public get roomsCount(): number {
        return this._roomsCount;
    }

    public set roomsCount(value: number) {
        this._roomsCount = value;
    }
}
class CommercialBuilding extends Reality {

    private _floorsCount!: number;

    public get floorsCount(): number {
        return this._floorsCount;
    }

    public set floorsCount(value: number) {
        this._floorsCount = value;
    }

    private _entry!: boolean;

    public get entry(): boolean {
        return this._entry;
    }

    public set entry(value: boolean) {
        this._entry = value;
    }

    private _adress!: string;

    public get adress(): string {
        return this._adress;
    }

    public set adress(value: string) {
        this._adress = value;
    }

    private _isUse!: boolean;

    public get isUse(): boolean {
        return this._isUse;
    }

    public set isUse(value: boolean) {
        this._isUse = value;
    }

    private _isAcces!: boolean;

    public get isAcces(): boolean {
        return this._isAcces;
    }

    public set isAcces(value: boolean) {
        this._isAcces = value;
    }

    private _building?: Building | undefined;

    public get building(): Building | undefined {
        return this._building;
    }

    public set building(value: Building | undefined) {
        this._building = value;
    }

    class Building {
    
        private _id!: string;
    
        public get id(): string {
            return this._id;
        }
    
        public set id(value: string) {
            this._id = value;
        }
    
        private _class!: string;
    
        public get classBuilding(): string {
            return this._class;
        }
    
        public set classBuilding(value: string) {
            this._class = value;
        }
    
        private _buildingYear!: number;
    
        public get buildingYear(): number {
            return this._buildingYear;
        }
    
        public set buildingYear(value: number) {
            this._buildingYear = value;
        }
    
        private _centerName?: string | undefined;
    
        public get centerName(): string | undefined {
            return this._centerName;
        }
    
        public set centerName(value: string | undefined) {
            this._centerName = value;
        }
    
        private _haveParking!: boolean;
    
        public get haveParking(): boolean {
            return this._haveParking;
        }
    
        public set haveParking(value: boolean) {
            this._haveParking = value;
        }
    
        private _isEquipment!: boolean;
    
        public get isEquipment(): boolean {
            return this._isEquipment;
        }
    
        public set isEquipment(value: boolean) {
            this._isEquipment = value;
        }
    }


Class diagram that demonstrates an inheritance hierarchy

As you can see, when i want to retrieve some announcements from the db, i can get different types of realty. I have no idea which way is the best to map response to an entity.
So I have just two solution of this problem:

Check responses properties with if and define type
Get responses in different functions, where i will know the response structure.

I have tried to find a solution in Google. But in most cases, people ask how to map an entity to a DTO.

Use Reactive Extensions (RxJS) https://rxjs.dev/guide/overview

The problem here is not clear. Are you getting an error? You say "The main problem is that deal and reality can have different properties", but the code example you give after that that you say doesn't work doesn't mention deal at all. Please [edit] your question to include a minimal reproducible example. This will make it much more likely that you will get an answer. When I tried it make an example based on your code https://tsplay.dev/mqg0dw it was missing a lot and I was not able to see the same problem you are describing.

I would add a type of realty (some kind of enum maybe?) to response and use a switch statement
switch(response.type) { 
   case realty1: { 
      MapRealty1(r); 
      break; 
   } 
   case realty2: { 
      MapRealty2(); 
      break; 
   } 
   default: { 
      throw new Error('Unsupported realty type'); 
      break; 
   } 
} 

There is no way your code will guess what is the type from nowhere - you need to provide this information somehow, since your your frontend doesn't now you backend classes this is imo the best way to tell it
